# how correctly write internal links in xslt file?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

i have xml file. i don't create internal link in xslt
i have xml file. i don't create internal link in xslt

```
<title id="introduction"> Intro </title>
<link linkend="introduction"> click here </link>
```

where is error in xsl file?

```
<xsl:template match="title">
<h2>
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</h2>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="link">
<a href="#{@linkend}">                       
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</a>     
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to show a bit more of your XSLT (for example, do you have a template that matches the `title` element). Also, you have tagged this "xsl-fo", but it looks like you are actually outputting HTML? Is this correct? Thanks!

Comment: added "title" template and without tagged "xsl-fo"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an "internal link" in HTML, you need to write out an anchor tag for your hyperlink to link to. (In other words, write out an `a` tag with a matching `id` attribute.

Try replacing your "title" template with this

```
<xsl:template match="title">
   <h2>
      <a id="{@id}">
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </a>
   </h2>
</xsl:template>
```